# TypeInitializationException When Using Moles With HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack, moles, typeinitializeexception

I am attempting to use Moles to test a non-static method in a separate assembly.  When running the test without the [HostType("Moles")] tag, the test runs fine.  When I replace it I receive the following error:

"The type initializer for 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' threw an exception."

I have attached code samples that perform in an identical manner.

Any help would be great!

**Class/method being called by the unit test**

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Web;

namespace HAPAndMoles
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void fooBar()
        {
            HtmlDocument foo = new HtmlDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using HAPAndMoles;
using Microsoft.Moles.Framework;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Web;

namespace HAPAndMoles
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [HostType("Moles")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Class1 bar = new Class1();
            bar.fooBar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace of the thrown exception, not only the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your example because in fact you don't use Moles.

If you just want to "Mole" our own non-virtual method, in the references of your test project you just have to right-click on the assembly of the tested project and choose **Add Moles Assembly**. That will create an HAPAndMoles.Moles reference.

Then add the corresponding using and you can call your class "moled" starting with M (Class1 => MCLass1). I show you an example testing the MClass1 behaviour:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using HAPAndMoles;
using HAPAndMoles.Moles;

namespace HAPAndMoles {
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [HostType("Moles")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            bool called = false;
            var bar = new MClass1() 
            {
                fooBar = () => called = true
            };
            ((Class1)bar).fooBar();
            Assert.IsTrue(called);
        }
    }
}
```

When I want Moles of mscorlib, I right-click directly on the references of the test project and I can **Add Moles Assembly for mscorlib**. Then  the

```
using Microsoft.Moles.Framework;
```

is needed.

Comment: Jeco ... Thanks for the info.  
I left some things out of my example to get it to its smallest form.  My original code did include the utilization of the moled code.
After reading your response, I noticed that I had neglected to create a mole for the HtmlAgilityPack assembly.